# Start X Not Working

Tags: startx

RaspberryPi2 with official RP 7" screen.

```
Formatted 16GB MicroSD using SDFormatterv4.zip = success
Installed Raspian Jesse using NOOBS v1_7_0.zip = success
```

Powered on & Appears to be a clean boot to Pi screen
Opened terminal window - typed `startx`

typing `startx` but it is throwing errors:

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
```

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest Raspbian Stretch with Desktop (currently 2017-09-07) :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Flash to sd card using Etcher (on Mac,PC,Linux) :

https://etcher.io

Note : sd card does not need formatting, nor the image file unzipping with this process

Place sd card into Pi and boot

Answer (score 0):

I've found this, although it's for ubuntu, debian and derivates... but might work. Try configure X for every one:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common`

and then choose "anyone".

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it using root.

```
   sudo startx
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudo startx takes me to the default desktop with root powers. This is not the right way to start the GUI!

For a while startx was not working on mi pi3. I had to change raspi-config to boot to desktop with password prompt. It was the only way to access the GUI.
For whatever reason, startx now works. I made no changes other than configuring to boot to console (startx still wasn't working) and back to GUI and back to console (and now it works). I pulled my hair out for nothing.